# EF Core 3.1 + Cosmos DB and Interceptor can work together?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, interceptor, ef-core-3.1

I try to use CosmosDb on Ef Core 3.1, it works but my goal is to use interceptor to inject a simple tenancy condition.
I don't found a lot of documention for cosmos, but for sql Server (At the beginning I thought it could work since ef Core is a layer built on top).

First i add new dependency:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.3" />
```

So i can use a simple class:

```
public class HintCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
                 DbCommand command,
                 CommandEventData eventData,
                 InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
        return result;
    }
...
```

And on builder, after UseCosmos i add: 
`.AddInterceptors(new HintCommandInterceptor());`

Don't works. I try to override all methods with console.Writeline but nothing was logged.

In the end I came to the conclusion that simply with a NoSql db (even if it has an SQL interface) the interceptors (or rather the DbCommandInterceptor) do not work since they are defined in a package that seems to be made for the relational db:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.3" />
```

So what I was trying to do was wrong.  Maybe there a specific way to do that without inheriting from DbCommandInterceptor, or maybe there isn't for NoSql db so i must build my own layer before each put/read operations.

Or maybe be there is a simple error or different way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you should consider [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).

Comment: @ GertArnold Thanks, i'll try it. Seems what i need :)